# Real-time Photo Updates - User Subscriptions

Tags: php, instagram

I'm having a few issues with subscriptions for **some** users on Instagram.  The subscribe challenge works correctly and most users get subscribed.  Their updates work completely as expected.

The [documentation](https://instagram.com/developer/realtime/) has 'myVerifyToken' I'm assuming that's the token of the user that's being subscribed or is this a random unique string I create to send?

Here is the result I get once I've subscribed:

```
{"meta":{"code":200},"data":{"object":"user","object_id":null,"aspect":"media","callback_url":"http:\/\/urlmremoved\/instagram","type":"subscription","id":"000000000"}}
```

This is telling me that a user subscription has been successful however, after having 6 people join my app and go through the oAuth process successfully the only POST's I receive are from the first member to be authenticated...

Subscription Code (works good for most users):

```
$checkin_url = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/subscriptions/";

        //$instagram[] for client_id, client_secret, redirect_uri
        $parameters = array(
            'client_id' => '{key}',
            'client_secret' => '{secret}',
            'object' => 'user',
            'aspect' => 'media',
            'verify_token'=>$access_token,
            'callback_url' =>  '{callback url}'
        );

        $curl = curl_init($checkin_url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $parameters);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $response = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
        $data = json_decode($response,false);
```

Incoming POST script (works nicely):

```
    // Catches realtime updates from Instagram
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']==='POST') {
         // Retrieves the POST data from Instagram
        $update = file_get_contents('php://input');
        $data = json_decode($update);

        foreach($data as $k => $v) {// can be multiple updates per call
        // load temp items into the database.
            $sub_id = $v->subscription_id; //Contains the JSON values
            $user = $v->object_id;
            $time = $v->time;
            $changed = $v->changed_aspect;

            $sql = "INSERT INTO temp (tempId,tempCode,tempData1,tempData2,tempData3,tempData4,tempLong,tempTime) 
                    VALUES (NULL, 'IG', '".$changed."', '".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."', '".$sub_id."', '".$time."', '".$update."', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)";

            $account->mysql_Query($sql);

        } // END foreach.

     } // END if
```

Answer (score 0):

Instagram only offers real time updates for all users that give your client API permission. When you subscribe to that endpoint, you will start receiving updates for accounts that have already authorized. After another user authorizes, you will receive those callbacks as well without having to subscribe again.

From the Instagram documentation:
`At the current moment we only allow you to subscribe to all users that have authenticated your application - not individual users.`

Comment: So what you're saying has confirmed what I was reading.  I only subscribe **once** to the users... then any user who goes through the oAuth process gets automatically added. Some users have gone through the auth process but their real time posts don't get pushed.

Comment: You only subscribe once to object->user with aspect->media and then you get ALL auth'd users posts. However, I'm experiencing a similar issue, lots of skipped posts from users who have auth'd.